# Any resources on how to setup a physical (test) cluster of mesos, cassandra and spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere, spark-cassandra-connector

I have been able to procure 4 physical machines to set up a spark test cluster. The data will be stored in cassandra, computation will be done with spark (sql and data frames). I am planning on using mesos, because, as a developer, I want to do as little infrastructure work as possible.

However, almost all tutorials I have found are from mesophere, using their *commercial* dcos infrastructure. I was able to configure the dcos cli to use marathon, but one of the mesophere support people told me that it may not work very well.

I was able to get cassandra installed, but marathon tells me that it's status is 'unhealthy.' Spark doesn't even get that far, Marathon tells me that the deployment task is failing, but there are no longs, no error messages, nothing.

Is it just a bad idea to use mesos? Is there an alternative? Any other resources on how to get cassandra and spark running? I don't mind purchasing books.

update: I am running CentOS 7 on all four machines. These machines have over 20 gigs of ram, 12 cpus and about a terrabyte of disk. One of them is setup as the master node (running zookeeper and mesos masters), the remaining machines are slaves/clients.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few good articles on how to install a cluster, like

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04
- https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/

Unfortunately, you don't give much details on your environment, such as the OS you're using.

Personally, I run Mesos on a CoreOS cluster in a completely dockerized manner, meaning that the Mesos Master and Slaves also run in an container. If you're intrested, have a look at

- https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-setup

to see my `systemd` setup to run Mesos on CoreOS.

Concerning Spark, there are several way to get it running on Mesos. Have a look at the Spark docs at

- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html

to get an idea. Furthermore, you can run [Spark-Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) in a Docker container, which will then act as client application for your Spark jobs (with REST API etc.). The Dockerfile/the image are available under

- https://github.com/tobilg/docker-spark-jobserver
- https://hub.docker.com/r/tobilg/spark-jobserver/

To run Cassandra as a framework on Mesos, have a look at

- https://github.com/mesosphere/cassandra-mesos

Comment: I updated my post with more details. I actually setup zk/mesos/marathon using the advanced course. However, their tutorial on setting up cassandra is broken. I emailed mesosphere about the broken link, they replied with a new set of instructions, which were for their commercial product.  I have also seen the digitalocean link, pretty good but it doesn't talk about installing cassandra. I've been trying to avoid docker, since that is yet another layer I have to learn, but I may have no choice.

Comment: You should find everything you need concerning Cassandra in the link to the Framework in my answer.